# Spring Boot - Keykloak Roles not available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, roles

**How can I bring the keycloak roles into my Spring boot application?**

After setting up the project, login and logout works fine, but the roles defined in keycloak are not available inside the spring boot application

I  have tried all kind of configurations inside keycloak. I could achieve that the Roles are available under Realm_access in the Spring security authentication, but just as an attribute.

[image]

I expected Spring to map these into authorities, so we can use hasRole etc.

Do I need to change the configuration inside spring or keycloak, to make this mapping happen or do I really need to map these manually?

The setup itself is very simple.

This is the properties file:

```
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-client.client-id=spring-client
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-client.client-secret=secret
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-client.scope=openid, profile, roles
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-client.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/spring-client
    spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spring-client.issuer-uri=http://127.0.0.1:28080/realms/spring-client
```

And the configuration:

```
        @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RTFM. Roles mapping is done differently for [OAuth2 clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities) (your case), for resource servers [with JWT decoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction), and for resource servers [with token introspection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-authorization-extraction), but doing it with Java conf is explained in details for each in Spring Security documentation.

If you prefer to define authorities mapping from application properties rather than writing Java code, you can have a look at [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#ease-openid-configuration--tests-in-spring-boot-3) (it will ease other aspects of your configurations too).

Note that **it is very unsafe to disable CSRF protection in a filter-chain with `oauth2Login()`** and more generally each time that security is based on sessions. I suggest that you read my [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) and tutorials.